# How do I get a rate per hour that can be negative into a positive score for ranking purposes?

Tags: statistics

I am writing a report that allows my employer to rank employees by productivity and fault rate. Employee ranks are based on productivity (value of 25%), supervisor input(value of 25%) and fault rate(50%). Catching a fault awards you a single point, causing a minor fault takes a point away, causing a major fault takes three points away. Using this number and the amount of hours tracked I want to get a "faults per hour" that is a positive number and use this to sum with the rest of the score in order to get a value with around 100 being the max that I can use to rank employees.

How do I properly calculate the fault rate per hour? The method I am considering is adding the score to a hundred and then weighting it according to time spent at the station, the issue that I'm having is I compare the final score to the average score at the station, how can I keep the average score of that station reasonable for comparison if I'm adding the results to 100?

So I guess I'm doing this

```
(x-3y - z + 100 / a) * b 

[x] is the amount of faults they have caught.
[y] is the amount of major faults they have created.
[z] is the number of minor faults they have created. 
100 is to get a positive number.
[a] is number hours spent at station.
[b] is the number hours spent on this station compared to total time
```

I'm dividing it by [a] because I need an hourly rate.

Since the period that I'm using as the baseline is 6 weeks and the period that I'm using to compare it is 6 weeks maybe I could just sum it all together and add the number to (100* 4) because it's 4 times the period size? These numbers don't have to be absolutely perfect because they will never be equal. Just looking to compare a 6week sample of a person's performance to a 6month sample of the entire average.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "add 100" strategy sounds ad-hoc and unrobust. Who says someone can't make so many mistakes that they use up the 100 bonus points per hour?

(And in any case, it should be $100\times a$ rather $\frac{100}{a}$ to make any amount of sense).

I would do something like
$$s_{\text{open}} = \frac{x-3y-z}{a}$$
to get a plain "average amount of good done per hour" (which can be positive or negative), and then use a [logistic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) to squeeze the open-ended scores into a finite interval:
$$s_{\text{percentage}} = \frac{100}{1 + e^{(\beta\frac{3y+z-x}{a})}}$$
Then the score for $x=y=z=0$ would be $50$; an overweight in caught mistakes makes the score increase towards (but not beyond) 100; and an overweight in committed mistakes makes the score decrease towards (but not lower than) 0. And averaging the $s_{\text{percentage}}$ scores would still make some sense.

Choose the $\beta$ parameter by trial-and-error for real-world sample data such as to produce a reasonable spread in the values.

(Strictly speaking, if we assume that $s_{\text{open}}$ is normal distributed, you should probably use the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) instead of the logistic function, but it is more involved to compute. However, if you have enough data to estimate mean and standard deviation for $s_{\text{open}}$, then the error function could be the way to go).

Comment: Is the e here this constant? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)

Comment: How do I work out e to the power of (3y+z-x/a)?

Comment: Why does it become 3y+z-x/a? Is that because of it being divided by 100?

Comment: What do I use for the values of e? The score?

Comment: Do I just use 2.718 to the power of the inverse of the score?

Comment: Yes, $e$ is Euler's constant. Most programming languages have a built-in function to compute powers of $e$ -- it's usually called `exp`, possibly `Math.exp`. (Beware, also that I put my $\beta$ in the wrong place, it should be in the exponent rather than before the $e$. As edited now).

Comment: How come in the second equation the signs are reversed?

Comment: Being in the denominator of the outer fraction already reverses the direction of growth once. The explicit sign reversal corrects for this, so that a higher $x$ will result in a higher overall score, and so forth.

Comment: Ahh! Clear, concise, thanks.